# What program is causing this runtime_error referencing Skin.cpp on line 87?

Tags: windows-10

Every time I start up my computer, I get an error dialogue saying

```
Error type: runtime_error
File: Skin.cpp
Line: 87

Skin bitmap not found
```

How do I track down what application is throwing this error? I am able to dismiss the error without any issues, but I still want to know if I can resolve this minor annoyance. I'm running Windows 10 on auto-update.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the [system internals process explorer.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
2. Reboot but don't close the dialog when it comes up.
3. Open the process explorer and look for an icon on the toolbar that looks like a gun sight.  "Find Windows Process"  [image]
4. Click the icon and select the title bar of the error message dialog.

Process Explorer will immediately highlight the process that is putting the dialog there.

If you need more information for the offending process, right click the highlighted process in the process explorer and select "Properties..." down toward the bottom of the menu.

If you really want to get fancy schmancy and want to learn yet another tool.. the "Process Monitor" can actually tell you what file it can't find.  This tool is difficult to learn how to manage but is very cool once you figure it out.